# (Newbie) Can someone please give me an example of activity-level preferences?

Tags: android, android-activity

Ok, this is how I have done the example of "Shared preferences", this is in my helper preferences class:

```
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";
```

and this is in one of my activitie's classes:

```
     SharedPreferences settings = 
         getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE); 
         SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit(); 
         prefEditor.putString("lastLaunch", returnTimeAndDateFormatted()); 
         prefEditor.commit();


         SharedPreferences settings2 = 
             getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
             if (settings2.contains("lastLaunch") == true) { 
//               System.err.println(settings2.getString("lastLaunch", "Default"));
                 Log.i("LASTLAUNCH", settings2.getString("lastLaunch", "Not LastLaunch value found!"));
             }
```

As I understand it I can access the variable "lastLaunch" from any of my activity classes which is all fine and dandy.

My book says there is also something known as "activity-level preferences" but does not give an example :(

Can someone give me an example (code) of this please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example would be to use the [getPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) method of activity.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit(); 
prefEditor.putString("lastLaunch", returnTimeAndDateFormatted()); 
prefEditor.commit();

SharedPreferences settings2 = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
if (settings2.contains("lastLaunch") == true) { 
    Log.i("LASTLAUNCH", settings2.getString("lastLaunch", "Not LastLaunch value found!"));
}
```

Here lastLaunch is private to this Activity.

Comment: Thanks for replying! And how do you set lastLaunch?

Comment: @Ryan same as in your example with the activityPreferences object.